# .tolist() converting pandas dataframe values to bytes

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, csv

I read a csv file in as a pandas dataframe but now need to use the data to do some calculations.

```py
import pandas as pd

### LOAD DAQ FILE
columns = ["date","time","ch104","alarm104","ch114","alarm114","ch115","alarm115","ch116","alarm116","ch117","alarm117","ch118","alarm118"]
df = pd.read_csv(cal_file,sep='[, ]',encoding='UTF-16 LE',names=columns,header=15,on_bad_lines='skip',engine='python')

### DEFINE SIGNAL CHANNELS
ch104 = df.ch104.dropna() #gets rid of None value at the end of the column
print(ch104)
```

When I print a ch104 I get [the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5zAp.png).

But I cannot do math on it currently as it is a pandas.Series or a string. The datatype is not correct yet.
The error if I do calculations is this:

```
can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

So what I tried to do is use `.tolist()` or even `list()` on the data, but then ch104 looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x71Wj.png).

I believe the values are now being written as bytes then stores as a list of strings.

Does anyone know how I can get around this or fix this issue? It may be because the original file is UTF-16 LE encoded, but I cannot change this and need to use the files as is.

I need the values for simple calculations later on but they would need to be a float or a double for that. What can I do?

Comment: what math are you trying to do and where does it fail ?

Comment: Could you provide an example which could be used to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You probably get this error because you're trying to make calculations on some columns considered by pandas as non numeric.  The values (numbers in your sense) are for some reason interpreted as strings (in pandas sense).

To fix that, you can change the type of those columns by using [**`pandas.to_numeric`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) :

```
df_obj = df.select_dtypes(['object'])
df[df_obj.columns] = df_obj.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip()) # to get rid of the extra whitespace

import re
cols = list(filter(re.compile('^(ch|alarm)').match, df.columns.to_list()))

df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

ch104 = df.ch104.dropna()
#do here your calculations on ch104 serie
```

Note that the 'coerce' argument will put NaN instead of every bad value in your columns.

> **errors{‘ignore’, ‘raise’, ‘coerce’}**, default ‘raise’ :
> If ‘coerce’,
> then invalid parsing will be set as NaN.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! I think this could work but when I did this code, before I used .dropna() I tried printing the columns and every value is now a NaN. Maybe something is wrong with the original format that I can't use this? I just don't know how to figure that out.

Comment: Maybe you should share a reproducible example, just a sample of your original data so we can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I just looked into the data. When I read it in, turns out there is an extra space " " between each of the numbers. I am going to try to get rid of this then apply your method. If you know anything about removing whitespace, not as a delimeter just extra whitespace, then let me know!

Comment: I updated my answer. We can apply a `str.strip()` to all the `object` columns to get rid of the extra whitespace right before applying the `pd.to_numeric(errors='coerce'))`.